# Show/hide span on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a span when an `li` with the class of `.image` is hovered, then preferably hide it once the mouse is removed from the li. I'm using the code below but to no avail.

**The HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="image">
    <span class="post_meta">Test &nbsp; 40in x 9in</span>
    <img src="http://web.com">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**THE CSS**

```
span.post_meta {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    bottom: 7px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 86px;
}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$docuemnt.ready() {
$(function() {
   $("li.image").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("span").show();
    },function(){
    $(this).parent().next("span").hide();
  });
 });  
});
```

Comment: Are you using `!important` anywhere in your css for `.post_meta`?

Comment: No - updating to show CSS

Comment: why are you using dom ready twice?

Comment: You also spelled `document` incorrectly here.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: just to be clear. the span starts out not displayed. then on hover it displays and then on hover out it hides again. If this is the case, shouldn't your css hide the span to start out with? So CSS should be display: none;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$(function() {
   $("li.image").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").show();
    },function(){
    $(this).find("span").hide();
  });
 });
```

Comment: You can also use `$(this).children("span")` instead of `find()` or `parent().next()`.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. Just need to figure out how to incorporate a fadeIn and fadeOut to this code and i'm golden.

Comment: @NikkiMather i realize i'm late, but you can accomplish the fade in fade out with css transitions and toggle class on the span instead of show hide.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this only with CSS

```
.post_meta {
  display:none;
}

li.image:hover .post_meta{
  display:block;
}
```

**Edit**

With Jquery try this:  View the Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/9RYhR/7/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.image').mouseenter( function() {
        $(this).children('span').fadeIn();
    });
    $('li.image').mouseleave( function() {
        $(this).children('span').fadeOut();
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to add a fade in and fade out to it too which is why i opted for this method.

Answer (score 0):

You spelled `document` incorrectly and didn't pass a callback, but that's not really needed as `$(function () { ... })` is an alias for `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`.

Try the following:

```
$(function() {
   $("li.image").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("span").show();
    },function(){
    $(this).parent().next("span").hide();
  });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realise that function was an alias for $(document).ready. The code, however, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #scope .post_meta{display:none;}
  #scope li:hover{cursor:pointer;}
</style>

<ul id="scope">
    <li class="image">
    <span class="post_meta">Test &nbsp; 40in x 9in</span>
    <img src="http://web.com">
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scope .image").hover(function() {
        $('.post_meta').show();
      },function(){
        $('.post_meta').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```